# Click a button in two pages at once

Tags: html, node.js, button, socket.io, click

I have two web pages as follows, when i click a button in one page alert box should be displayed in both pages, How can i achieve this. How can i click two buttons in two different web pages at once

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res){

        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
 });
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log("server started");

var SOCKET_LIST ={};

var io = require("socket.io")(serv,{});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){


    socket.id = Math.random();
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;
    console.log("socket connection");

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
        console.log("Disconnected");
    });

    socket.on("button",function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
});

    socket.emit('servermsg', $("button").click(function() {
              alert("I am an alert box!");
     }));



});

setInterval(function(){
    for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
        var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
    }
}, 1000/25);
```

index.html (client)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
var socket =io();



socket.emit('button',function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
});

socket.on('servermsg', function(data){
console.log(data.msg);
});
</script>



<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What does that even *mean*?  How are these two pages related?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @David i dont know how to connect those two page so seeking for solutions.

Comment: are these pages shown in iframes?

Comment: @vamshi: "Connect those two pages" doesn't make sense, so you're unlikely to find "solutions".  Describe what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  There's a very good chance that you're doing the wrong thing, and asking for ways to do the wrong thing doesn't often go well.

Comment: @David i was thinking to use socket.io to communicate between the two pages this is like client-server communication but i am unable to do that

Comment: @vamshi: I recommend that you stop thinking about the technical implementation for a minute and try to understand the problem you're actually trying to solve.  Currently you can't even *describe* the problem, which is going to make solving it pretty close to impossible.

Comment: @David i want to trigger a button in another HTML page by clicking a button in one HTML page and i just started this so i want to know what are the different ways i can do this

Comment: @vamshi: A web browser window can only show ***one*** page at a time.  What you're asking, by itself, makes ***no*** sense.  Clearly there's more context to what you're doing, but you are ***refusing*** to share that context with us.  Unless you can describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, nobody can help you.

Comment: @David  i open the two webpages in two tabs in a browser and both webpages have same domain

Comment: @vamshi: Since the only thing the pages share is that they're both open in your browser then it sounds like you need to write a browser plugin of some kind.  There's *probably* a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.  But since whatever you're trying to do is top secret, it'll be up to you to find it.

Comment: @David thanks for your assistance i appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: If your other page is listening then yeah.

Comment: @Faiz99 how to make other page listen?

Comment: via sockets, use websockets or socket.io for quick start. Both of your pages should be connected. When you push an event on one page your other page should be in event loop to handle that event.

Comment: @Faiz99 i'm new to sockets can i have an example

Comment: You should go with MartinWebb answer.

Comment: try my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of Curiosity i just tried MartinWebb's answer. I hope it might give you a start.

Page # 1:

```
<button type="button" onclick="hello()">Hello</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // window.localStorage.removeItem("text");
    function hello() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("text","Hello there..");
    }
</script>
```

Page # 2:

```
<p id="show"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('storage', storage_event_listener, false);

    function storage_event_listener(evt)
    {
        document.getElementById("show").innerText = evt.newValue;
        // console.log(evt);
    }
</script>
```

You can see i have commented a line on my page # 1. It is because "The storage event is fired on the window object whenever setItem(), removeItem(), or clear() is called and actually changes something. For example, if you set an item to its existing value or call clear() when there are no named keys, the storage event will not fire, because nothing actually changed in the storage area."

So, while experimenting i had to clear my storage item in order to invoke the event.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the two pages. That means they both sit on the same domain www.adomain.com.

You can do this using local-storage.

On the click event of the first page store a value key in localstorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

In the second page add an event listener to "hear" the localstorage change.

http://html5demos.com/storage-events

When that event fires click your button

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Or Option 2

Use https://www.pubnub.com

This is a drop in io socket msg service. You can get a free account send a message from one page, listen for it on another and react. In your case click the button.

Comment: Or if you want to get real smooth add pubnub realtime api, Create a channel, listen on second page, Get the message, click the button. www.pubnub.com

Comment: This is a nice solution.